# Applying the __add__ operator on all fields of a Python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, pydantic

I have a class for which I want to overload `__add__` to mean adding all fields between `obj1` and `obj2`.
I am currently leveraging `.__fields__` and `getattr()`.
This works but feels a little ugly?

Imagine the class is an N dimensional vector, with a non-example code `__add__`:

```py
class NDVec(BaseModel):
    # basic
    dim1: int
    dim2: int
    # ....
    dimN: int

    def __add__(self, obj2: "NDVec"):
        # all fields
        return NDVec(
            **{
                field: getattr(self, field) + getattr(obj2, field)
                for field in self.__fields__
            }
        )
```

```py
>>> vec1 = NDVec(dim1=5, dim2=10, dimN=17)
>>> vec2 = NDVec(dim1=17, dim2=0, dimN=5)
>>> vec1 + vec2
NDVec(dim1=22, dim2=10, dimN=22)
```

Comment: The discussion between me and another user about whether the question is MRC or not is available in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/146980).

Answer (score 4):

> This works but feels a little ugly?

Unfortunately when metaprogramming, the code will tend to look a little dodgy. Looking at your answer we can see you solved the 'issue' by creating another function.

I agree with creating another function, as you move the less pleasant code out. Doing so allows you to DRY your code if you need to implement `__sub__`. However, I would take the operator you want to apply to the objects in as an argument to allow reuse of the function across different dunder methods.

I would also validate all the operators are actually of type `T` at run time. You can use the `__debug__` dunder to disable the check when running Python in optimized mode; `python -o`.

```py
def reduce_fields(
    operator: Callable[[Any], Any],
    self: T,
    *others: T,
) -> T:
    cls = type(self)
    if __debug__:
        for other in others:
            if not isinstance(other, cls):
                raise TypeError(f"{other!r} is not of type {cls.__name__}")
    fields: dict[str, Any] = {}
    for field in self.__fields__:
        value = getattr(self, field)
        for other in others:
            value = operator(value, getattr(other, field))
        fields[field] = value
    return cls(**fields)


class NDVec(BaseModel):
    # basic
    dim1: int
    dim2: int
    # ....
    dimN: int

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return reduce_fields(operators.add, self, other)
```

The function `reduce_fields` is rather specialized. You can abstract the function to interact with dictionaries rather than types. Doing so allows for a more interoperable experience, with less jank in the `reduce` function. However the code is obviously a little less maintainable.

```py
class IFields(Protocol):
    @property
    def __fields__(self) -> Iterable[str]: ...


def to_dict(obj: IFields) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return {
        key: getattr(obj, key)
        for key in self.__fields__
    }


def reduce_dict(
    operator: Callable[[Any], Any],
    source: dict[str, Any],
    *others: dict[str, Any],
) -> dict[str, Any]:
    if __debug__:
        keys = set(source)
        for i, other in enemurate(others, 1):
            if (missing := set(other) - keys):
                raise TypeError(f"other ({i}) missing keys {missing}")
    fields: dict[str, Any] = {}
    for key, value in source.items():
        for other in others:
            value = operator(value, other[field])
        fields[field] = value
    return fields


class NDVec(BaseModel):
    # basic
    dim1: int
    dim2: int
    # ....
    dimN: int

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(**reduce_dict(operators.add, to_dict(self), to_dict(other)))
```

Answer (score -4):

I ended up doing something more like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)


def add_object_fields(obj1: T, *args: T, **kwargs: T) -> T:
    all_args = [obj1] + list(args) + list(kwargs.values())
    return type(obj1)(
        **{
            field: sum([getattr(obj, field) for obj in all_args])
            for field in obj1.model_fields
        }
    )
```

Comment: This is not a good answer on code review. A good answer on code review makes at least one meaningful observation about the original code. This answer might be okay on Stack Overflow, but not here. I suggest you read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the differing approaches.